# Query recent posts by author

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-field, wp-query, recent-posts

I'm fairly new to wordpress but trying to get recent posts by a specific author. The following code displays only most recent bog posts. I am using a custom field to get the author ID.

EDIT by vancoder:
By which I mean, I am using the ACF plugin, which allows the selection of 1 or more WP users, the api returns the selected user objects

Any suggestions would be amazing ...

```
<?php $current_user = get_field('username');
if( $current_user ) : ?>
<div id="related-posts">
    <h3 class="divider-header"><span>Knowledge Community Articles</span></h3>
    <?php $userID = $current_user->ID;
    $args = array(
    'author' => $userID,
    'showposts' => 2,
    'caller_get_posts' => 1
    ); 

    $query = new WP_Query($args);
    if( $query->have_posts() ) {
    while ($query->have_posts()) : $query->the_post(); ?>
        <div class="article-excerpt<?php echo ' excerpt-' . $c; ?>">
            <h4><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h4>
                <div class="post-meta">
                <div class="post-author">By <a href="<?php echo get_author_posts_url(get_the_author_meta( 'ID' )); ?>"><?php the_author_meta('display_name'); ?></a></div>
                </div><!-- .post-meta -->
            <?php the_excerpt(); ?>
        </div><!-- .article-excerpt -->
        <?php endwhile; } ?>
        <a href="<?php echo get_author_posts_url(get_the_author_meta( 'ID' )); ?>">More from this Contributor &rarr;</a>
        </div><!-- #related-posts -->
<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: What is the exact value of `$current_user`?

Comment: Are you just getting posts for any particular author that has been queried? couldn't you just copy twentytwelve's `author.php` and alter as needed?

Comment: I have edited the question to explain the custom field / $current_user stuff.

Comment: What is the value of `$current_user->ID`?

Comment: Thanks vancoder. That's correct. 'username' is the custom field used to input the user id. So $current _user is whichever user ID i input. Just trying to set up profile pages for individual authors that display their latest posts. Hope that explains it. Thanks for the help. Ill take a look at author.php